# How to delete one link from Chrome adress bar?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I've read on superuser that I need to press FN + Shift + Backspace but it seems not to work anymore.

How do I do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Press shift + delete when it shows up in Blue. It'll remove it from the URL suggestions

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks anyway